# special characters not displaying properly

Tags: managed-package, app, operators

Special characters such as ≠ or ≥ are displaying as question marks on a single customer's site.

My app is a managed package and these characters appear correctly on all other instances, so I figure there must be something wrong with the locale or encoding settings this customer's site. Does anyone know how I might access these site settings, or possibly a different cause?

Comment: Can you add the site's locale info? also a site that is working info will assist.

Comment: This does seem an encoding issue. Ive seen this happen with the Russian Script when data was loaded in with files that didn't support utf-8

Comment: Have you installed the critical update going around regarding html rendering and escaping? I wonder if that might affect it?

Comment: I think you have to ask Salesforce to do something with the charset - I seem to remember having an issue with a US org a few years ago.

Comment: it's this happening on "na0" by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

Data created within the org by user activity will display correctly as the encoding is handled in the users settings.

Data that is loaded into the org, into your custom objects will need to be loaded with the correct character set.

Assuming that dataloader is used to load this data in, then ensure that utf8 is checked within the settings, additionally the csv data file that is created to be loaded must be saved in utf8 character set.

*Note if using Excel to generate the csv file the default character set is ANSI, so "special characters" will be lost/corrupted and (display as question mark when loaded). You need to specify the encoding option during the export from Excel: (Save Dialog, Tools Button, Web Options Item, Encoding Tab).