# Visualforce: Rendering PDF with international characters and bold/italic - Arial Unicode MS not working

Tags: visualforce, pdf

I just had the problem to create a VF page that renders as a pdf and outputs polish text. The only font that supports polish characters is Arial Unicode MS but with this font, I can't output bold or italic, the renderer simply ignores it. The other fonts work as expected but there the special characters are missing.

Anyone out there who found a workaround to format the text in bold/italic with Arial Unicode MS?

Comment: Are you using custom CSS and do you have an <apex:pageMessages id="messages"> tag on your page? I've found that if **anything** goes wrong while processing a page, it can cause all sorts of other formatting problems. For the special characters, have you tried using their c-map numbers in order to get them to display? As a final thought, are the fonts installed on the machine you're using to view the PDF?? I don't know if they always get embedded in SF's PDF generator which is an option one can set with Acrobat Distiller.

Comment: I ran across [this post](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3774/special-characters-not-displaying-properly) today and wondered if you'd seen it. Perhaps it might provide some insight into your problem and lead to a possible solution.

Answer (score 3):

After version 27, users have to add **applyBodyTag="false"** to render double-byte PDF as usual.

```
<apex:page ... renderAs="pdf" **applyBodyTag="false"**>
```

ref: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_quick_start_renderas_pdf.htm

Answer (score 2):

Relaying my findings from the more recent question: [visualforce page as PDF - unicode font bold characters](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/118055/102)

---

According to [Flying Saucer PDF Generator and Unicode](http://minaret.biz/tips/fs/index.html#arial) you need a special variant build of Flying Saucer to:

> generate the appropriate PDF commands to emulate bold and italics when a style calls for it but no matching font can be found.

From the Features of this Release:

> Added font emulation for bold and italics variations when there is no direct support in the font files themselves. Fonts like Microsoft's Arial Unicode MS only come in one version: plain text. In order to have bold, italics and bold+italics the font must be modified on-the-fly by the PDF display software.

So, unless Salesforce were using a variation of Flying Saucer or switch to another PDF renderer it won't be possible.

As per the comment by Oleksiy, voting for the idea [Arial Unicode MS - Bold in PDF](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DfdiAAC) may help in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have your CSS styling wrapped in `<head> </head>`?  Normally, this wrapper isn't needed for Visualforce, but I've found it necessary to have my CSS classes work when rendering as a PDF.

---

### My PDF Template

```
<apex:page 
    showHeader="false" 
    sidebar="false"
    standardStylesheets="false"
    renderAs="pdf"
    docType="html-5.0"
    applyHtmlTag="false"
    applyBodyTag="false"
>
    <html>
        <head>
            <style type="text/css" media="print">
                @page {
                    margin: 0.1in;
                }

            </style>
        </head>
        <body>

        </body>
    </html>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: That makes no impact. I have outputText in my pdf page and I add inline styles to it. For example, I add red color and font-weight 800, without renderas="pdf" text is red and bold, but as pdf it is red only

Comment: Inline styles always work.  Whenever I make PDFs, I have `<apex:page applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false" ...>` and manually add the `<html>` and `<body>` tags.  Then I put my CSS Classes in a `<head>`.

Comment: But in this case issue is with font only. I have the same issue - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/118055/visualforce-page-as-pdf-unicode-font-bold-characters?noredirect=1#comment165941_118055