# Rendered Special characters romanian in PDF

Tags: visualforce-component, pdf, visualforce, dynamic

I am creating a PDF using Visualforce Dynamic components where i show data from Map Object. This data contains text a Romanian Language with special characters such as ă,ș,ț...

This data gets rendered properly on Visualforce HTML page but does not appears on the PDF version.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here are two useful links where people had the same problem.

Some suggest that adding applyBodyTag="false" to render double-byte characters will help.

```
<apex:page ... renderAs="pdf" **applyBodyTag="false"**>
```

[Visualforce: Rendering PDF with international characters and bold/italic - Arial Unicode MS not working](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10052/visualforce-rendering-pdf-with-international-characters-and-bold-italic-arial)

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000958LIAQ

Comment: Thanks @kazoolsky for your answer. But, i've already tried this solution and i have formatted the text with Arial Unicode MS. However, just some special romanian characters (not all) appear on the PDF.