# visualforce page as PDF - unicode font bold characters

Tags: visualforce, pdf, css, font, flying-saucer

I am creating PDF page in salesforce and I have to use cyrillic characters in page. As font I set up 'Arial Unicode MS' in css, because cyrillic characters are not rendered with other fonts. But I need some text to be bold.

From this page https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_supported_fonts.htm I see that I can use only 'Arial Unicode MS'. But how can I make text bold?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/18662/12440) ? >>After version 27, users have to add **applyBodyTag="false"** to render double-byte PDF as usual.

Comment: @Oleksiy didn't help unfortunetely

Comment: [Looks like it's not possible](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DfdiAAC) :(

Comment: Have you tried using any inline CSS/HTML tags?

Comment: @crmprogdev I have outputText in my pdf page and I add styles to it. For example, I add style="font-weight: 800; color: #FF0000;", without renderas="pdf" text is red and bold, but as pdf it is red only

Comment: I'm speaking of actually using the tag `<bold>`. The Flying Saucer Render engine is soo old I seriously doubt it has any idea what a font weight of 800 is. With flyingsaucer, you generally want to either specify fonts in ems, points or pixels. And for paper media, pixels is not a wise choice.

Comment: @crmprogdev that does not help. font-weight: bold; works for Verdana, I tried it, but cyrillic characters are displayed only for Arial Unicode MS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Flying Saucer PDF Generator and Unicode](http://minaret.biz/tips/fs/index.html#arial) you need a special variant build of Flying Saucer to:

> generate the appropriate PDF commands to emulate bold and italics when a style calls for it but no matching font can be found.

From the Features of this Release:

> Added font emulation for bold and italics variations when there is no direct support in the font files themselves. Fonts like Microsoft's Arial Unicode MS only come in one version: plain text. In order to have bold, italics and bold+italics the font must be modified on-the-fly by the PDF display software.

So, unless Salesforce were using a variation of Flying Saucer or switch to another PDF renderer it won't be possible.

As per the comment by Oleksiy, voting for the idea [Arial Unicode MS - Bold in PDF](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DfdiAAC) may help in the long run.